# Who owns the IP developed in the VentureStar program?

Tags: launch-vehicle, ssto

The VentureStar program including the prototype X-33 cost upwards of $1 billion, surely some of that went into still meaningful intellectual property. Who would own it now? NASA provided the funding, so did they have ownership after the cancellation of the program? If not NASA then it would have been owned by Lockheed Martin, but if so, would it have been transferred to ULA when it was created?

Comment: It was a joint venture wasn't it - hence the name.